# Java grammar production rule syntax of Oracle manual

Tags: java, syntax, context-free-grammar

I have a syntatic doubt about a Java program grammar rule mentioned in [Oracle Java specification manual](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-10.html#jls-ArrayInitializer). Here is an approximation of that rule, to the extent that SO's HTML restrictions allow it.

```
ArrayInitializer:
  { [VariableInitializerList] [,] }

VariableInitializerList:
  VariableInitializer {, VariableInitializer}
```

It is given in [section 2.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-2.html#jls-2.4) of Java manual. `[x]` denotes zero or one occurrences of `x` and `{x}` denotes zero or more.

However, I have the following doubts,

1. For *ArrayInitializer* non-terminal, the first curly brace `{` denotes a terminal curly brace or the syntactic meaning I mentioned above.
2. Also, for *VariableInitializerList* non-terminal, I know that `{, VariableInitializer}` means something equivalent to regex `(a,b)*`, but this kind of grammar will also accept some other string which does not actually fit the criterion, won't it?
3. I also want to confirm if the square brackets in the first production denote the regex or simple terminals.

I find this grammar specification confusing. Can you help me understand it?

Answer (score 1):

The Java specification uses font styles to distinguish between literal characters, as found in the input, and grammatical symbols (non-terminals and grammar operators). Literals are shown in `fixed width`, while grammar symbols are shown in *italics*.

That's a pretty subtle distinction, particularly for certain punctuation symbols [Note 1]. Fortunately, the only punctuation used as grammar operators are brackets and braces, and it's not that hard to see whether a brace is slanting (italic) or upright. The brace in *ArrayInitializer* is upright, and the bracket is slanting, as is the brace in *VariableInitializerList*. So the brace in *ArrayInitializer* is a literal character. The brackets in that production indicate that the enclosed grammar symbols are optional, and the braces in *VariableInitializerList* indicate that the enclosed symbols can be repeated any number of times, including zero. (That's effectively the Kleene `*`-operator, which, as you say, is used in regular expressions.)

I trust that answers your questions (1) and (3). I don't really understand your question 2. Note that the comma in *VariableInitializer { , VariableInitializer }* is a literal character (it's not in italic) so what's being described is a non-empty comma-separated list of initializers. I don't know why you think that differs from other Kleene star operators.

---

#### Notes

1. It doesn't help that a CSS bug affects  the examples in section 2.4, which supposedly illustrate the grammar. The CSS forces everything in a "note" to be italicized, thereby hiding the distinction between grammar operators and literal characters.

Comment: For point 2, I thought that because a Kleen operator * actually produces all combination of terminals, right? for eg. regex (a,b)* will accept aabb. If the same fashion is followed the commas will be repeated in java grammar and it will get accepted. But I think the comma and `VariableInitializer` are continued and they are not considered two separate token but one continuous token and that will generate correct grammar. Correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: @DeepakSangle: `A = {a.b}` is a set of two elements. `A*` is indeed all possible concatenations of elements of the set. Contrast that with `B = {ab}`, which is a set of one element, the strong `ab`. `B*` is the set of all concatenations of that element: `{ε, ab, abab, ababab...}`. The difference is not the operator; it's the set being operated on. Concatenation of two sets, whether explicit or through the Kleene star, is always a Cartesian product, so `AB` is `{aab, bab}`.

Comment: A non-terminal in a contrxt-free grammar can be thought of as the set of all sequences (of tokens) which can be derived from that non-terminal. A token (like `,`) stands for a singleton set containing that token. Concatenation works just as with regular expressions; it is the Cartesian product of the concatenated sets. (But they are token sequences rather than character strings).The Kleene star is just the same: any number of concatenations of the elements of the set.